# "yum update" failed in Cent OS 6.4

Tags: centos

Got strange error on Cent OS 6.4.  I started a new Cent OS 6.4 and here is what I got:

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your repo data has gone stale, corrupt, or something has changed since you last updated.

Please try `yum clean all` and then try `yum update` again and see if that has resolved your issue.

If it's still not working check the `epel.repo` file which you should find located at `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` you should expect to see something like this (extracted from my file)

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```